# How to query with where clause in WCF service while retrieving data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am creating a WCF service accessing data from a SQL Server database. Since I am new to this, I am not able to add a `where` clause in the query. Please tell me how can I retrieve data for some particular parameter. Posting my code below

`IServices1.cs`:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
               UriTemplate = "GetAllCustomers")]
    List<Consumer> GetAllCustomers();
```

`Service.svc.cs`:

```
 namespace JSONWebService
 {
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
       public List<Consumer> GetAllCustomers()
       {
           NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
           List<Consumer> results = new List<Consumer>();
           Consumer consumer = new Consumer();

           foreach (Output_Master cust in dc.Output_Masters)
           {
               results.Add(new Consumer()
               {
                   Record_ID = cust.Record_ID,
                   MeterCycle = cust.MeterCycle,
                   Agency = cust.Agency,
                   WorkDate = cust.WorkDate
               }

               return results;
           }
      }
```

`Consumer.cs`:

```
namespace JSONWebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Consumer
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string Record_ID { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string MeterCycle { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string Agency { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public decimal? WorkDate { get; set; }     
    }
```

Comment: Which column u need to use where ..?

Comment: Your service.svc.cs code is wrong

Comment: @SambathKumarS please suggest the change, by the way if I am executing this code without where clause, I am getting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetAllCustomers` method should be more like this:

```
public List<Consumer> GetAllCustomers() {
   return
      new NorthwindDataContext()
      .Output_Masters
      .Where(consumer => consumer.SomeParameter == someValue)
      .ToList();
}
```

This does assume that `Output_Masters` is a collection of `Consumer`. You might actually need to be referencing a `Customers` or `Consumers` property instead, but it depends on the design of your `NorthwindDataContext` class.

If `NorthwindDataContext` implements `IDisposable`, which it probably does, then the method should actually look more like this:

```
public List<Consumer> GetAllCustomers() {
   using (var northwind = new NorthwindDataContext())
      return
         northwind
         .Output_Masters
         .Where(consumer => consumer.SomeParameter == someValue)
         .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you: Doubtful with NorthwindDataContext - Is list or datareader ?
so i have use list where

```
public List<Consumer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
    List<Consumer> results = new List<Consumer>();
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
    foreach (Output_Master cust in dc.Output_Masters)
    {
        results.Add(new Consumer()
        {
           Record_ID = cust.Record_ID,
 MeterCycle = cust.MeterCycle,
 Agency = cust.Agency,
 WorkDate =cust.WorkDate
     });
}
///examble
results = results.Where(i => i.Record_ID == "1").ToList(); 
return results;

}
```

Comment: @Smbath Kumar S when I am adding results = results.Where(i => i.Record_ID == "1").ToList(); to my code for some correct value of Record_ID, It is giving me blank out put as {"GetAllCustomersResult":[]}.

Answer (score 0):

use lambda expressions :

```
results = results.Where(i => i.YourColumnName == paramvalue).ToList();
```